# painting on JPanel line is not connected

Tags: jpanel, double, line, draw

I was trying to make a chart using the JPanel paint method with Graphics2D draw shape. However, my lines are not connected and they have a slope of 0. My expectation was plotting the line like a signal wave. Here is my code:

```
package action;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Starter extends JFrame {
double Xoffset = 30, Yoffset = 20, Xold = 40, Ycurr = 40, Xcurr = Xold, 
Ytarget = Ycurr, Xgap = 10, Ygap = 60;
double sh = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight();
double sw = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth();
int panelOffSet = 20;

double[] value_old = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
double[] value_curr = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 
};// new

// double[17];
    int counter = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Starter mainThread = new Starter();
}

public Starter() {
    super("EEG Recorder");
    // //set the frame to center of screen
    setLayout(null);
    this.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(32, 32, 32));
    setSize((int) sw, (int) sh);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    // add the painting panel
    EEGRecorder plotter = new EEGRecorder();
    add(plotter);
    this.setVisible(true);
    while (true) {
        plotter.run();
    }
}

class EEGRecorder extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    public EEGRecorder() {
        setLayout(null);
        setBackground(new Color(32, 32, 32));
        setBounds(0, panelOffSet, (int) sw, (int) (sh - panelOffSet));
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            this.updateUI();
            repaint();
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // System.out.println("hello");
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D gg = (Graphics2D) g;
        for (int i = 1; i < 17; i++) {

            Random rn = new Random();
            Ytarget = rn.nextDouble() * 30;
            value_curr[i] = Ytarget;
            // System.out.println(value_curr[i]);

            if (Xcurr + Xgap - 1 > sw) {
                gg.clearRect((int) Xoffset, (int) Yoffset, (int) (sw - Xoffset - 20), (int) (sh - panelOffSet));
                gg.setColor(new Color(32, 32, 32));
                gg.fillRect(0, 0, (int) (sw), (int) (sh - panelOffSet));
                Xold = Xoffset;
                Xcurr = Xold + Xgap;
            } else {
                gg.setColor(Color.yellow);
                gg.drawString("ch" + i, 4, (int) (Yoffset + (i - 1) * Ygap));
                if (counter == 0) {
                    value_old[i] = 0;// value_curr[i];
                    Xcurr = Xold + Xgap;

                }
                gg.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                gg.draw(new Line2D.Double(Xold, (i - 1) * Ygap - value_old[i], Xcurr,
                        (i - 1) * Ygap - value_curr[i]));
                double Yold=(i - 1) * Ygap - value_old[i];
                double Ynew=(i - 1) * Ygap - value_curr[i];
                System.out.println(Xold+","+Yold+","+ Xcurr+","+Ynew);
            }
        }

        value_old = value_curr;

        // Ycurr = Ytarget;

        Xold = Xcurr;
        Xcurr += Xgap;
        counter++;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: i am still trying to figure out the problem in this code, anyone any idea ?

Comment: `while (true) {` massively dangerous in this context; `this.updateUI();` has nothing to do with what you're trying to do, it would seem you're just randomly calling methods which "sound" good - I'd suggest reading the docs on `updateUI` and basically, never call it again

Comment: You've also broken the documented paint chain, which is going to produce no end of issues - I would highly recommend having a read of [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Comment: Also paint methods should not be updating the state, they should just paint the current state.  You should reduce as much of the logic down as you can so as many of the decisions are made else where - why? Paint can be called at any time for any number of reasons, many of which you don't control

Comment: Painting is also destructive.  It is expected that each time paint is called, you will repaint the entire state, not just update it.  This leaves you with two choices.  Either you devise a model which can maintain the information need for the component to paint itself completely OR you paint to a backing buffer.

Comment: Using `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight/Width()` also a bad (for what you're trying to use it for), instead, simply call `setExtendedState` and pass it `Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH`, this will allow the window to take into consideration other OS elements, like the task bar

Comment: thanks for the update , as you have said , i was using methods which will supposedly do the job and did not care what trouble it might bring . i am little bit new to Java .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could spend a lot of time trying to explain to you why you code isn't working and how to fix it, needless to say, you need to step back and make a lot of changes.

I would highly recommend that you take the time to have a read through:

- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)
- [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)
- [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Now, because of the way painting works in Swing, you have two choices.

Either you use some kind of model to maintain the information you wanted painted, and when a paint cycle occurs, you update the component with this information OR you draw to a backing buffer and paint that to the component when a paint cycle occurs

I've chosen to use a data model, it's simpler in that I don't need to monitor the state of the component and update the buffer, but that's me.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Starter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Starter mainThread = new Starter();
            }
        });
    }

    public Starter() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("EEG Recorder");
        EEGRecorder plotter = new EEGRecorder();
        frame.add(plotter);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
//        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class EEGRecorder extends JPanel {

        double Xoffset = 30, Yoffset = 20, Xold = 40, Ycurr = 40, Xcurr = Xold,
                Ytarget = Ycurr, Xgap = 10, Ygap = 60;

        private List<List<Point2D>> series;

        public EEGRecorder() {
            series = new ArrayList<>(16);
            for (int line = 0; line < 16; line++) {
                series.add(new ArrayList<>(100));
            }
            setBackground(new Color(32, 32, 32));
            Timer timer = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    update();
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected void update() {
            int count = 1;
            for (List<Point2D> line : series) {
                Point2D last = new Point2D.Double(0, 0);
                if (line.size() > 0) {
                    last = line.get(line.size() - 1);
                }

                Random rn = new Random();
                double y = (rn.nextDouble() * 30) + (Yoffset + (count - 1) * Ygap);
                double x = Xoffset;

                int sw = getWidth();
                if (last.getX() + Xgap - 1 > sw) {
                    line.clear();
                } else {
                    x = last.getX() + Xgap;
                }

                line.add(new Point2D.Double(x, y));
                count++;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.

            Graphics2D gg = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            int count = 1;
            for (List<Point2D> line : series) {
                gg.setColor(Color.yellow);
                gg.drawString("ch" + count, 4, (int) (Yoffset + (count - 1) * Ygap));
                gg.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                Point2D fromPoint = null;
                for (Point2D toPoint : line) {
                    if (fromPoint != null) {
                        gg.draw(new Line2D.Double(fromPoint, toPoint));
                    }
                    fromPoint = toPoint;
                }
                count++;
            }
            gg.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

What this doesn't do is start the series from the beginning, but maintain some of the old information when you reach the end of the component, I simply clear the series and start again.

To have it "overlap" would require a much more complex model and I'm to lazy

Comment: thanks for the enlighting . your code is working ,i am trying to figure out why mine did not work . basically what i did seems reasonable for me at least , but i have spent like 5 hours trying to figure out the problem .what exactly did i do wrong in my code ?

Comment: The two core problems.  You `run` loop, which could block the EDT or otherwise update the UI from outside the EDT, in either, a bad idea and the fact you didn't call `super.paint`, thereby breaking the paint chain - while this doesn't "look" bad, `Graphics` is a shared resource amongst Swing components, meaning anything that was previously painted to the context will still be there when it's given to you, part of the paint chains responsibility is to prepare this context for painting before the component is painted